# Struts ActionForm Replace with ValidatorForm

Tags: java, validation, struts, struts-1

Does replacing `ActionForm` with `ValidatorForm` below will cause any change to the existing logic?

```java
public class EditForm extends ActionForm {

existing logic(setters(), getters(), reset(), validate() )

}
```

**with**

```java
public class EditForm extends **ValidatorForm**{

existing logic(setters(), getters(), reset(), validate()  --> **will it be affected?**

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`ValidatorForm`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts-core/1.3.10/org/apache/struts/validator/ValidatorForm.java) is a subclass of `ActionForm` and you could use it in this context. If you change it to `ValidatorForm` it will perform basic validation provided by the default implementation of `validate` method.

The logic might change because the class `ValidatorForm` overrides some methods of its superclass.

Comment: Thanks, Currently the Editform is being used by only one action and the form already has a validate() method and it validates 2 fields.Will this method be affected if I change Editform to extend ValidatorForm?

Comment: Depends on if you use XML validation or not, but it overrides the `validate()` method for it.

Answer (score 0):

The real diference is:

> This class extends `ActionForm` and provides basic field validation ***based on an XML file***. The key passed into the validator is the action element's `name` attribute from the `struts-config.xml` which should ***match*** the form element's name attribute in the `validation.xml`.

However, the logic that might change is what to do when there is a validation error.